# How can I have CMake from Homebrew put symlinked path to itself in generated files?

Tags: macos, cmake, homebrew

Using a M2 Mac, I have Homebrew and CMake installed in their default location.

When I run CMake, it finds the executable at `/opt/homebrew/bin/cmake`, which is correct.  This is a symlink to `../Cellar/cmake/3.26.4/bin/cmake`, which was also correct.

However, in the files it generates, it hardcodes the CMake location to `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.26.4/bin/cmake` in the `Makefile` which breaks as soon as CMake is updated.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Upgrading CMake generally requires you to manually regenerate your build system. This is only one such reason.

Comment: It isn't a version check; rather, it is a path check, and that is highly dependent on how CMake is installed.  For instance, if one downloads CMake directly from https://cmake.org/download/, install it in the usual place, and add /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/ to the beginning of your path, this never manifests.  If one really had to manually regenerate their build system for every CMake update, this seems like a glaring problem that Kitware has had for years!

Comment: CMake has had countless glaring problems for years.